# Linq query with Array in where clause?

Tags: .net, sql, linq

I have searched for this, but still can't seem to get this to work for me.  I have an array of Id's associated with a user (their Organization Id).  These are placed in an int[] as follows:

```
int[] OrgIds = (from oh in this.Database.OrganizationsHierarchies
                       join o in this.Database.Organizations on oh.OrganizationsId equals o.Id
                       where (oh.Hierarchy.Contains(@OrgId))
                          || (oh.OrganizationsId == Id)
                       select o.Id).ToArray();
```

The code there isn't very important, but it shows that I am getting an integer array from a Linq query.

From this, though, I want to run another Linq query that gets a list of Personnel, that code is as follows:

```
List<Personnel> query = (from p in this.Database.Personnels
                                where (search the array)
                                select p).ToList();
```

I want to add in the where clause a way to select only the users with the OrganizationId's in the array.  So, in SQL where I would do something like "where OrganizationId = '12' or OrganizationId = '13' or OrganizatonId = '17'."

Can I do this fairly easily in Linq / .NET?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

While this is probably better suited to a join, you can use this:

```
List<Personnel> query = 
    (from p in this.Database.Personnels 
    where OrgIds.Contains(p.OrgID) select p).ToList();
```

This will translate into SQL something like..

```
where OrgID in (1,2,...,n)
```

Comment: Yes sir!  You are correct.  I, of course, figured this out about 2 minutes after I posted this (which I posted in frustration after 2 hours of attempts)

Anyway, I ended up making the int[] a List<int>.  Not sure if that affects the above solution or not.  But that's how I got it to work.

Comment: This saved me a double foreach loop

Comment: Cool, can this be done using the object syntax instead of query syntax?

Comment: @TheLegendaryCopyCoder: By "object syntax" do you mean using the extension methods directly instead of using the query syntax? If so, sure. `var query = this.Database.Personnels.Where(p => OrgIds.Contains(p.OrgID)).ToList();`

Answer (score 7):

A check using the `Contains` method should do the job here.

```
var query = (from p in this.Database.Personnels
             where OrgIds.Contains(p.OrganisationId)
             select p).ToList();
```

Comment: you submitted 1 minuted too slow to be marked as answer.  :-)  +1

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to give Adam credit for the answer, but I also wanted to share the code I used to make this work:

```
List<int> OrgIds= (from oh in this.Database.OrganizationsHierarchies
                       join o in this.Database.Organizations on oh.OrganizationsId equals o.Id
                       where (oh.Hierarchy.Contains(@OrgId))
                          || (oh.OrganizationsId == Id)
                       select o.Id).ToList();

List<Personnel> query = (from p in this.Database.Personnels
                                where (OrgIds.Contains(p.OrganizationId))
                                select p).ToList();
```

### Thanks all,

-Matt

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this,
OrgIds.ToList.Contains(p.OrginizationID)

Though really I would do it more like this:

```
var OrgIds = (from oh in this.Database.OrganizationsHierarchies
                   join o in this.Database.Organizations on oh.OrganizationsId equals o.Id
                   where (oh.Hierarchy.Contains(@OrgId))
                      || (oh.OrganizationsId == Id)
                   select o.Id);
List<Personnel> query = (from p in this.Database.Personnels
                            where (OrgIds.Contains(p.OrigizationID)
                            select p).ToList();
```

That way the final query to get personnel will execute containing the combined query from both.