# Iterating through Collection to build a Where statement for Azure Table Query on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I have a query I need to create to get a list of objects (Lets call them **Cats**) from a database stored remotely through `Microsoft Azure` on **Windows Phone 8**.

In order to get this list of objects (**Cats**) I have to iterate through a list of other objects to pull out the foreign key, lets call it a list of **CatHomes**. But I also want all cats called **Bob**.

I know how to get all **Cats** called **Bob**:

```
  private async void getCatsForCatHomesOrCalledBob(Collection<CatHome> homes)
  {
    // get a list of cats that have visited the cat homes in the collection
    IMobileServiceTableQuery<Cat> query = catTable
                                            .Where(cat => cat.Name == "Bob");

    Collection<Cat> items = null;
    // add the items to a list
    items = await query.ToCollectionAsync();
  }
```

but how do I also iterate through the `Collection` of **CatHome** objects and add them to the query, to build it up?

I am aware that I could do something like:

```
IMobileServiceTableQuery<Cat> query = 
   catTable.Where(cat => cat.Name == "Bob" || cat.HomeId == 1
                    || cat.HomeId == 2);
```

Which doesn't allow me to iterate through the `Collection`, what I want to do is something like:

```
IMobileServiceTableQuery<Cat> query = catTable.Where(cat => cat.Name == "Bob");
foreach(CatHome home in homes){
  query.AddOrStatement(cat.HomeId == home.Id);
}
```

But cannot find a way to do this.

Is there an alternative? Ideally I would like to be able to pass a `String` variable to the `Where()`, so as I can build up the SQL statement as a `String`, but cannot find a means to do that either.

There is similar functionality for **Android** and **iOS** where you can build up the expression using `.Or()` or `.And()` methods, which aren't present in `IMobileServiceTableQuery` in **WP8**, and things like `Skip()`, which is present.

I am aware that I could iterate through the list of **CatHome** objects and do a query for each one, adding the results to a master list, but that seems like a bad use of the phone's resources.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `homes`in `foreach(CatHome home in homes){` is a list you can just do this:

```
IMobileServiceTableQuery<Cat> query = catTable.Where(cat => cat.Name == "Bob" && homes.Contains(cat.HomeId));
```

Not sure if the IEnumerable.Contains works to, but converting `homes` into a `List<CatHome>` should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is already answered [Linq query with Array in where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836491/linq-query-with-array-in-where-clause). Get the list of foreign keys first and then use it in contains where clause